# How can I create a Dashboard for my Ethereum ICO investors to track their Tokens

Tags: solidity, ether, ico, crowdsale, tokens

We're launching an Initial Coin Offering (ICO) and I would like to create a user dashboard for investors to track their tokens and the progress of the crowdsale.

How can I do this? I'm a web developer with PHP skills and looking to build this dashboard on the back of the token website.

Is there a way to do this in Wordpress, Magento?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you using NodeJS and web3js library to interact with ethereum. It would not be really hard to get into NodeJS of you are a web developer.

My team and I opened a source code of the dashboard so you can pick it, modify and use. It's already tested in real world and passed security audit.

Here is [backend](https://github.com/JincorTech/backend-ico-dashboard).
API docs can be found [here](https://jincortech.github.io/backend-ico-dashboard/).
Frontend app is [here](https://github.com/JincorTech/frontend-supreme-happiness)

Feel free to fork and modify as you want. Stars and contributions are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what libraries are available in PHP for interacting with ethereum but you could start by using the [json RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) interface on an ethereum node.

Since most ERC20 tokens have events that are triggered for allocations and transfers you can query the node using [eth_getLogs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getlogs) to get information about how the sell is progressing and also look at the balance of the contract itself. Specifically for users to view their token allocations - this can be done client side with web3js and calling an ERC20 function called [balanceOf](https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens/blob/master/contracts/StandardToken.sol) (which is only a `call` not a `sendTransaction`. You don't even have to host the node in this case, you can use [INFURA](https://infura.io/) as a provider.

Honestly most of this can be done client side with web3js and the contract ABI but I find the user experience better if you store and update the progress you get from eth_getLogs server side in a cache and present it to users on page load. Bonus points if you open a websocket and update that information to users as the sale progresses.

Answer (score 0):

the investors doesn't need dashboard to track tokens, they can see all details from contract on etherscan.io
if you want to do some helpful code to make track easy for them you can use APIs from [etherscan](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/apis)

Comment: This answer very fundamentally misses one of the core tenants of a decentralized world: you don't need to trust anyone. Use the RPC.

Comment: You don't *need* to trust anyone but it makes life easier currently as all sorts of tools are not very well developed yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sdk available inside PHP to transfer tokens on Ethereum network. I have done it with ethereum/web3.js javascript sdk for one of my client. For backend i would suggest making rest api in nodejs and then call it from web frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these guys:

https://www.google.ru/search?q=ico+investor+dashboard

http://icoadm.in is a pretty good service.

Answer (score 0):

ICOForo's state of the art ICO Dashboard is well defined & customizable. Also had multi-wallet integration, KYC Documentation & multilevel secure Features.
http://icoforo.com/icodashboard/